# Run NodeJS programs all requiring different versions of node

Tags: node.js, windows, environment, nvm

I know this is an old problem, and I've gotten so far with other answers, so I'm using nvm for windows, I have my Node V11 and Node V12 versions installed, but when I do:

```
nvm use 11.15
```

The windows User Escalation popup comes up saying "Do you want to change the settings for CMD.exe?".

Ideally, I'd want to just switch the environment of my current process (from VSCode Terminal) or possibly use the nvm tool in a batch file to ensure that I can run different NodeJS solutions side-by-side on the same machine i.e. using different versions of node at the same time. Is this possible without requiring admin escalation?

Thanks